# How to access Microstack instances on br-ex from other LAN devices?

Tags: lan, network-adapter

I have Microstack installed in a Virtualbox VM with bridged adapter(192.168.0.27/24 subnet).

The microstack instances under 10.20.20.0/24 subnet can access the internet as well as the other machines on my LAN.The guest VM host on which microstack is installed can ping the instances.

However, I cannot access the Microstack instances from any other machine on my LAN network/other guest VMs. How to configure br-ex to allow incoming traffic?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else is also struck with this issue, FYI, microstack automatically configures the public url access. Hence, you can access it from any other machine using the localhost IP address of the machine on which you installed microstack.

Here in my case, I can access it via 192.168.0.27. Use http:localhost:5000/v3/ for keystone credentials.
Source: https://opendev.org/x/microstack/commit/6eaf44bbfa8b5784a8d9b16e85cecc989502460f